# What are the effects of "\t" , "\r" and "\b" in c?

Tags: c

I'm a little confused about the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     printf("\nab");
     printf("\bsi");
     printf("\rha");
     return 0;
}
```

When I execute the program on Linux, it prints

```
ha
```

But when I execute it on Xcode, it prints

```
absi
ha
```

I am a little confused about "\t", "\b" and "\r", and I can't figure out how the program works.

Comment: The program works exactly the same. Different terminals interpret control characters differently, that's why you see different results. The correct question is not "how `\r` works in C" but "how `\r` works in a Linux terminal". The language you use to output that `\r` is irrelevant.

Comment: @n.m. actually the C standard specifies how `\r` *should* work. Xcode just doesn't abide by that.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The standard says what `\r` is intended to do on display devices. Is XCode console window a display device? There's no definition of what constitutes one, hence only "intended" and not anything stronger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\t` refers to a tab character, `\r` to a carriage return (think of a typewriter), and `\b` to a *nondestructive* backspace. As crvv pointed out, the same output is always sent to stdout: `"\nab\bsi\rha"`. However, your terminal and XCode will produce different output (by choice).

Your terminal will do the following: it sees the `\n`, goes to a new line, it sees `ab` and "stores" that, but then it sees `\b`, so it performs a *nondestructive backspace.* This basically means the cursor, aka the point where new characters are written, goes back one space:

Initially:

```
ab
  ^
```

After encountering `\b`:

```
ab
 ^
```

Note that the cursor is now under b, so it will be overwritten if any subsequent characters result.

Next, it reads in `s` and then `i`, so we get:

```
asi
   ^
```

Next, it reads in `\r`. This is the carrage return, which on old typewriters would return the cursor to the beginning of the line. So now we have:

```
asi
^
```

Finally, it reads in `ha`, and because the cursor is under `a`, `ha` will overwrite `as`:

```
hai
  ^
```

Here's the thing. Note that your cursor is *still* under i. It is not under the next empty space, after the i. Because your program `printf` does not print anything after `printf("\rha")`, when the terminal prints your output, the cursor will remain under i.

So, what is the next thing your terminal outputs? Usually, it's the normal prompt, i.e. `yourname@ubuntu`. *This overwrites the i*, hence, you will see something like `hayourname@ubuntu`.

Xcode, on the other hand, does things a little differently. It consumes the `\b`, so the cursor doesn't go back a character, and the `\r` is treated as a newline, hence:

```
absi
ha
```

Comment: But after \b is si, b will be overwritten and it will be "asi" and then once encounters "\rha" it should output "hai" I think...

Comment: @Victoria see my edited response; I realized what the issue was, hopefully that helps.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you :)

Comment: @Victoria Please consider accepting this answer if you believe it answers your question satisfactorily and better than other answers

Answer (score 0):

The program always writes "\nab\bsi\rha" to its stdout.

The difference comes from how this is displayed.

You can use `gcc hello.c && ./a.out | xxd` to see it.

```
00000000: 0a61 6208 7369 0d68 61                   .ab.si.ha
```

Answer (score 0):

`\r` is `CR` (carriage return) code. It returns the cursor to the start of line. You have "ab", then `\b` which is backspace. Following "si" will overwrite "b" and you have "asi". Then `\r` goes to the start of line and "ha" is printed in the place of "as" - the result is "hai". But the cursor is after "s" and when Bash prompt is displayed, it replaces "i" because it is the first free position after cursor. And you see "ha{prompt-message}". Add `\n` after `\rha` to see "hai".

Comment: What is bash prompt?

Comment: @Victoria If your shell in Linux is `bash`, then bash prompt is the text in command line before you star typing command, like `user@host ` or `C:\>` in DOS. This text is called Prompt. Bash prompt is "the prompt of bash shell".

Comment: I have tried adding \n after \rha and I saw "hai". I understand now. Thank you!